# Geo location /time zone in Application Insights

Tags: azure, timezone, cloud, azure-application-insights

I have embedded Application insights telemetry in my azure cloud application, basically it’s a web based application.

I can see many things in azure portal after login, but unable to find geo location of request like we can see in Google analytic.

Can any one help me to find where I can see Geo location of request or at least time zone of request in azure portal?